# Docker pull gives error unkown blob for microsoft/windowsservercore

Tags: windows, macos, docker

I've mac OS as my host operating system and trying to pull an windows image microsoft/windowsservercore . While downloading it gives unknown blob error.

Docker version is 17.03.0-ce and shows OS/arch as linux/amd64. Would it be helpful if I change the  OS/arch similar to the below: 
https://i1.wp.com/blog.docker.com/wp-content/uploads/docker-for-windows-switch.gif?zoom=1.25&w=1140&ssl=1/

If so, could some one help me on how to switch to windows container from MAC

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I am pretty sure that you cannot run a Windows container anywhere but on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pull and run Docker Windows container images, you have to have a Windows machine available. On macOS, you'd have to run Windows 10 or Windows Server 2016 in a VM. Here are some resources for getting set up:

- https://github.com/docker/labs/tree/master/windows/windows-containers
- https://github.com/StefanScherer/docker-windows-box